# Sympy thinks the same variable is two different variables

Tags: python, sympy

Sorry for the messy title, but let me explain. I have a long code doing a bunch of manipulations on an expressions including (among others) a function f=sp.Function('f')(x,y). My end result is some huge expression, but I noted that there are terms that look like

```
 f^3(x,y)f(x,y)-f^4(x,y)
```

and it completely fails to simplify this to zero. This makes the expressions much longer than they should be and thus very had to handle. Does anyone recognize this problem? How can I force sympy to know that f and f are the same function?

I can not provide a working example since the code is very long, and I was not able to identify a small subcode that gives the same problem. If you need the output or have some idea how I can manipulate the output to identify what the problem is, please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `simplify` function on the end result.